# Parsing a nested string object using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to parse a nested string object to return an object.

For instance, given a string:

```
'{dog : cat, joe: { jane: cat, peanut : dog }, fat : skinny}'
```

I'd like to convert it into an object data type, so the return value would be:

```
{dog : cat, joe: { jane: cat, peanut : dog }, fat : skinny}
```

**Code so far:**

```
function Parse(string) {
  if (string[0] == '{' && string[string.length - 1] == '}') {
    const inObj = string.substring(1, string.length - 1);
    const arr = inObj.split(',');
    const keyVal = arr.map(c => c.split(':'));

    const obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < keyVal.length; i++) {
      let ele = keyVal[i];
      if (ele[1].startsWith('{')) {
        let string2 = ele[1];

        for (var j = i + 1; i < keyVal.length; i++) {
          console.log(keyVal[j]);
          if (keyVal[j].endsWith('}')) {
            string2 += keyVal[j];
            break;
          } else {
            string2 += keyVal[j];
          }
        }
        obj[ele[0]] = JSONParser(string2);
      } else {
        obj[ele[0]] = ele[1];
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
}
```

My logic flow, roughly:

1. If the string starts with `{` it will start parsing.
2. Make a substring that gets everything between `{` and `}`
3. Split the string up into an array with the separator `,`
4. Make each element (each element should be a key-value pair string) into a subarray splitting up the key and the value into a subarray. So it should be `[[key,value],[key,value]]`;
5. **PROBLEM:** the value can be another object.
6. Try to iterate through `[[key,value],[key,value]]`.
7. If `value == '{'` then start making a string for it
8. The string will first be the value.
9. Iterate through the `[[key,value],[key,value]]` starting at
   the element value with `{` + 1 index.
10. Add onto the string until the element endsWith `}`.
11. Should end up with the nested object string.
12. Recursively use
    our `JSONParse` to parse the object.

If someone could help with how they would parse the object or maybe correct my current logic I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: If you want to make your own parser, have a look at https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json_parse.js

Comment: He's clearly trying to teach himself how to write a parser.

Comment: if this was to parse correctly you would get a 'cat' undefined error ? maybe im missing something... otherwise you could just use eval(string) ....

Comment: I would use `indexOf`, `lastIndexOf`, `substr` and `split`. And at first `.replace(/ /, ""), that makes everything easier.

Comment: Will JSON.parse method solve your problem ?